# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg'

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

[image]

my project structure mentioned above, In test_a.py trying to import func present in a.py

```
from pkg_1.code.a import sample
```

> Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_1'

(base) C:\Test\pythonT1>C:/Users/%%%/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python.exe c:/Test/pythonT1/pkg_1/test/test_a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Test/pythonT1/pkg_1/test/test_a.py", line 1, in 
    from pkg_1.code.a import sample
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_1'

Comment: Ignore it, i have it correctly in my file, Typo while typing here

Comment: How are you running file d.py? Through app.py?

Comment: from pkg.subpkgB.d import (funcName)

Comment: yes but where? in app.py? How are you actually running your code. Post the full stack trace rather than just one line of the error.

Comment: I have updated my question, with proper example, Could anyone pls help in that?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment but I'm posting it as an answer due to the formatting limitations of comments. Try this:

```
--pkg
  --src
    --pkg  
      --a.py
      --__init__.py
  --tests
    --__init__.py
    --test_a.py
```